# Proving Properties in Ordered Fields

Tags: ordered-fields

Refer to Definition 1.3, which states, an ordered field is a field F that is ordered set with the following additional properties:

```
If x>0 and y>0, then x+y>0.
If x>0 and y>0, then xy>0.
x<y if and only if y-x>0.
```

Prove that property (3) implies property (1).  Be certain to use only properties that have been proved or already assumed to be true.

Comment: Which properties have already been proven and which properties may you assume?

Comment: These have already been proved:

Let F be a field and let a be any element from F.

-1*a = -a

-(-a) = a

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a > 0$ and $b > 0$. We want to show that $a + b > 0$.

Now take $y = 0$ and $x = -b$. Then since $0 - (-b) = b > 0$, it follows by property $(3)$ that $-b < 0$. But since $0 < a$, it follows by the transitivity of $<$ that $-b < a$. Hence, by taking $x = -b$ and $y = a$, it follows by property $(3)$ that $a - (-b) = a + b > 0$, as desired.